# Angular 2 unauthorized response(401)

Tags: angular, http, authentication, http-headers

I am writing an application that require user authentication to access certain functionalities. When authenticated user login, the server generate JSON Web Token (JWT). i saved the generated token in localstorage. To make post, delete and update certain data from database, credential is required in the header . I used angular io documentation to set up request header. However, i got unauthorized response(401) when i make post request. Here is the post request and the header

```
createItem(name: string, text: string) {

  const body = JSON.stringify({noteData: {name: name, text: text}});
  const headers = new Headers();
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/text' );
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  const options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(this.createNote, body, options)
                     .map(this.extractData);
```

}

```
     private extractData(res: Response) {
         return res.text() ? res.json() : {};
   }
```

// here is the request header error response

```
    Request URL:http://localhost:4500/api/notes
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:401 Unauthorized
    Remote Address:[::1]:4500
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade


    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:0
    Date:Wed, 26 Jul 2017 03:08:45 GMT
    Vary:Origin
    X-Powered-By:Express


   Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
   Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
   Authorization:Bearer "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjM3ZTY3MDQ3LTY0MjQtNDZkMi04NjI0LTdhZmVlYjMyZTdlZiJ9.NEKOQpQIsjYpUHKh061Jl_9-Zz_Ude5MkcsGrOLetKU"
   Cache-Control:no-cache
   Connection:keep-alive
   Content-Length:43
  Content-Type:application/text
  Host:localhost:4500
   Origin:http://localhost:4200
  Pragma:no-cache
  Referer:http://localhost:4200/note
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

// function to login and set localstorage

```
   login(username: string, password: string) {
    const body = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    const options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(this.loginUser, body, options)
                     .map((res: Response) => {
                        const token = res.json() && res.json().token;
                        if (token) {

          localStorage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(res.json().token));
                        }

                    })
                     .catch((error: any) => 
           Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Comment: Could you try it by calling from postman,let me know your call is success or not.

Comment: And as you said you tried of giving space at Bearer `headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);` could you update the question once again so that no one mistake your question.

Comment: @k11k2  unauthorized response in postman request as well

Comment: @mulugetZeleke Then it is all about your token,your token is not valid one. right now it's not about your headers.verify with valid token until postman response is 202. and check your code with valid token.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space after Bearer:

```
createItem(name: string, text: string) {

  const body = JSON.stringify({noteData: {name: name, text: text}});
  const headers = new Headers();
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/text' );
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token); //<-- added space after 'Bearer'
  const options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(this.createNote, body, options)
                     .map(this.extractData);
}
```

Comment: There must be some issue with the token. Can you validate that the token you are sending in the request header is valid (i.e. that the token you retrieve from local storage is the same token that you received from the token producing service? Also, is the content type correct for the api? Perhaps it should be application/json, but that may not create a 401 error in any case.

Comment: I saved in local storage what is generated from token producing service

Comment: I'm suggesting that you inspect the actual headers that are sent, perhaps in the dev console, to ensure that the value saved and retrieved is as you expect.

Comment: What was the outcome?

Comment: headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) is  customized by back end owner. he/she  configure authorization like this: headers.append('authentication-token',  token)